# Warning in quantstrat

Tags: r, trading, quantstrat

Here is my code:

```
library(quantstrat)
suppressWarnings(try(rm(list=ls(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument),pos=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument),silent=TRUE))

currency("EUR")
stock("ATX",currency="EUR",multiplier=1)
ls(envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)
ls(all=T)

initDate <- '1999-01-04'
startDate <- '1999-01-05'
endDate <-  '2014-09-25'
initEq <- 1e6

Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

## ----echo=FALSE,results='hide'-------------------------------------------
if(file.exists("ATX.RData"))
{
  load("ATX.RData")
} else {
  getSymbols('^ATX', from=startDate, to=endDate, index.class="POSIXct", adjust=T)
  save(list="ATX",file="ATX.RData")
}  

##

b <- BBands(HLC=HLC(ATX["1999"]), n=20, sd=2)

##
rm.strat("multiAsset.bb1") # remove portfolio, account, orderbook if re-run
initPortf(name="multiAsset.bb1", "ATX", initDate=initDate)
initAcct(name="multiAsset.bb1", portfolios="multiAsset.bb1",
         initDate=initDate, initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio="multiAsset.bb1", initDate=initDate)

#
strategy("bbands", store=TRUE)
#
add.indicator("bbands", name = "BBands",
              arguments = list(HLC = quote(HLC(ATX)), maType='SMA'), label='BBands')

#Sell short when the close crosses above the upper band
add.signal("bbands", name="sigCrossover",
           arguments=list(columns=c("Close","up"),relationship="gt"),
           label="Cl.gt.UpperBand")

# Buy long when the close crosses below the lower band
add.signal("bbands", name="sigCrossover",
           arguments=list(columns=c("Close","dn"),relationship="lt"),
           label="Cl.lt.LowerBand")


add.signal("bbands", name="sigCrossover",
           arguments=list(columns=c("High","Low","mavg"),relationship="op"),
           label="Cross.Mid")

###
add.rule("bbands", name='ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(prefer="Close",sigcol="Cl.gt.UpperBand",sigval=TRUE, orderqty=-100,
                        ordertype='market', orderside=NULL),type='enter')

add.rule("bbands", name='ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(prefer="Close",sigcol="Cl.lt.LowerBand",sigval=TRUE, orderqty= 100,
                        ordertype='market', orderside=NULL),type='enter')


add.rule("bbands", name='ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(prefer="Close",sigcol="Cross.Mid",sigval=TRUE, orderqty= 'all',
                        ordertype='market', orderside=NULL),type='exit')

##
SD = 2
N = 20

##
out <- applyStrategy("bbands",
                     portfolios="multiAsset.bb1",parameters=list(sd=SD,n=N))

##
updatePortf("multiAsset.bb1")
updateAcct("multiAsset.bb1")
updateEndEq("multiAsset.bb1")
```

When I run `updatePortf("multiAsset.bb1")`, this appears:

```
updatePortf("multiAsset.bb1")
[1] "multiAsset.bb1"
Warning messages:
1: In getInstrument(p.ccy.str) :
  instrument USD not found, please create it first.
2: In .updatePosPL(Portfolio = pname, Symbol = as.character(symbol),  :
  CurrencyUSD not found, using currency multiplier of 1
```

`Question 1`:
What I am doing wrong, so the following above appears? I want to use `EUR` for the currency, not `USD`.

`Question 2`:
Is it correct that when I specify `prefer="Close"` in `add.rule` the `ruleSignal` function will use the next days close for the trading price?

Best Regards

Comment: `initPortf` and `initAcct` have a `currency` argument that defaults to `"USD"`, not `"EUR"`, and you did not define `currency("USD")`.  Also, you could use `rm_instruments()` and `ls_instruments()` instead of `suppressWarnings(try(rm(list=ls(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument),pos=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument),silent=TRUE))` and `ls(envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)`, respectively

Comment: @GSee thanks! But do you have an answer to question 2?:)

Comment: I believe that the answer to 2 is "yes," but I haven't used quantstrat in a few years.  I think that at some point in time it treated daily data differently than intraday data, and I don't know for sure what the current behavior is.  It's probably documented somewhere.  [Here's a thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/qantstrat-same-period-execution-td4652598.html) that might answer your question, but I only skimmed it